# Installing `diction` on CentOS 4

Tags: centos, packages, rpm

I have a need for [diction](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diction) to be installed on my server, which is running CentOS 4. I can find it no problems for [Fedora](http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=diction&submit=Search+..) and Ubuntu (apt-get 'just worked'), but am having no luck under CentOS.

Which Fedora package would I need, or is there a solid source link I can use? Seems like searching only brings back "dictionary" rather than "diction".

Comment: You can run `rpm -qip name-of-dicionRPM-for-fedora.rpm` to see if the RPM information specifies the URL that the source code is from

Comment: @JeffG - thanks .. was unaware of the `ip` args!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to prompting from @[JeffG](https://serverfault.com/users/63166/jeffg), I was able to find the source `tgz` on [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/diction/diction.html).

It would still be nice to be doing this from a package standpoint, but since it has not been updated since 2007, installing from source seems safe enough.

Steps followed:

- `rpm -qip diction-1.11-4.fc12.i686.rpm`

output from above command:

```
warning: diction-1.11-4.fc12.i686.rpm: V3 RSA/MD5 signature: NOKEY, key ID 97a1071f
Name        : diction                       Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.11                          Vendor: Fedora Project
Release     : 4.fc12                        Build Date: Sat Jul 25 07:30:33 2009
Install Date: (not installed)               Build Host: x86-6.fedora.phx.redhat.com
Group       : Applications/Text             Source RPM: diction-1.11-4.fc12.src.rpm
Size        : 187412                        License: GPLv3+
Signature   : RSA/8, Thu Jul 29 01:58:51 2010, Key ID 421caddb97a1071f
Packager    : Fedora Project
URL         : http://www.gnu.org/software/diction/diction.html
Summary     : Identifies diction and style errors
Description :
Diction and style are two old standard UNIX commands. Diction identifies wordy
and commonly misused phrases. Style analyses surface characteristics of a
document, including sentence length and other readability measures.

These programs cannot help you structure a document well, but they can help to
avoid poor wording and compare the readability (not the understandability!) of
your documents with others. Both commands support English and German documents.
```

- download from source point - http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/diction
- `tar zxf diction-1.11.tar.gz`
- `cd diction-1.11`
- `./configure ; make ; make install`